# Mod Rewrite and 404 redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want make **websitename.com/file.php** become **websitename.com/file/** and after browsing thru StackOverflow, with countless try and error, this is what I got and it is working.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/$ $1.php [NC]
```

I also added this to header.php so that if any filename shows up with the .php extension, it will redirect to the 'slashed' URL I wanted.

```
$NoPhpUrl = $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' ? 'https' : 'http';
$NoPhpUrl = $NoPhpUrl .'://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if(strstr($NoPhpUrl , ".php"))
{
    $NoPhpUrl = str_replace(".php","/", $NoPhpUrl );
    header("Location: ".$NoPhpUrl );
}
```

The issue I have currently is when I type this link **websitename.com/file** (without slash at the end), it will go to a 404 page.

I'm ok with the 404 page if the file does not exist in the directory.
But if it does, is there a way to force the slash to appear at the end of the url (if file exist) without making it go to 404?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try your rules this way and also turn off multiviews. I added force trailing slash as *I would do it* in Apache instead of PHP. Server side should be preferred versus code redirects.

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

#force trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks! The force trailing slash works but if the file don't exist in the directory, the page keep loading for a while and this appear: websitename.com/filenoexist.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php/

Comment: Ok I modified the last rule a little bit.

Comment: IT IS PERFECT!! Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

check in your if condition, you're replacing .php with /. so, this is the reason why you can't access in path without /. check out.